# ActionMailer.net Standalone - Layouts

Tags: actionmailer.net

Are layouts possible with ActionMailer.net Standalone? I've tried several different permutations, but can't seem to get layouts to work.

Comment: No, never did. Also, the processing of the templates is insanely slow...

Comment: Same here, just went for MVCMailer in the controllers instead, to bad because I like having mailing inside the business logic.

Comment: Funny that regular ActionMailer has layout support but the standalone seems different.